# Perl Regex To Remove Commas Between Quotes?

Tags: regex, perl, quotes

I am trying to remove commas between double quotes in a string, while leaving other commas intact? (This is an email address which sometimes contains spare commas). The following "brute force" code works OK on my particular machine, but is there a more elegant way to do it, perhaps with a single regex?
Duncan

```
$string = '06/14/2015,19:13:51,"Mrs, Nkoli,,,ka N,ebedo,,m" <ubabankoffice93@gmail.com>,1,2';
print "Initial string = ", $string, "<br>\n";

# Extract stuff between the quotes
$string =~ /\"(.*?)\"/;

$name = $1;
print "name = ", $1, "<br>\n";
# Delete all commas between the quotes
$name =~ s/,//g;
print "name minus commas = ", $name, "<br>\n";
# Put the modified name back between the quotes
$string =~ s/\"(.*?)\"/\"$name\"/;
print "new string = ", $string, "<br>\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
$string =~ s/(?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*\K(?:,|"(*SKIP)(*FAIL))//g;
```

pattern details:

```
(?: # two possible beginnings:
    \G(?!\A) # contiguous to the previous match
  |          # OR
    [^"]*"   # all characters until an opening quote
)
[^",]*     #"# all that is not a quote or a comma
\K           # discard all previous characters from the match result
(?:          # two possible cases:
    ,        # a comma is found, so it will be replaced
  |          # OR
    "(*SKIP)(*FAIL) #"# when the closing quote is reached, make the pattern fail
                      # and force the regex engine to not retry previous positions.
)
```

If you use an older perl version, `\K` and the backtracking control verbs may be not supported. In this case you can use this pattern with capture groups:

```
$string =~ s/((?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*)(?:,|("[^"]*(?:"|\z)))/$1$2/g;
```

Comment: I tried it but got the following error message:Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*K(?:,|"(* <-- HERE SKIP)(*F))

Comment: @Duncan: if backtracking control verbs are not supported you can use: `$string =~ s/(?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*(?:\K,|("[^"]*(?:"|\z)))/$1/g;`

Comment: I changed it to $string =~ s/(?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*\K(?:,|"(?!))//g;, but now it runs but does not remove the commas. My Perl version is 5.8.8.

Comment: Still no luck - with $string =~ s/(?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*(?:\K,|("[^"]*(?:"|\z)))/$1/g; it runs but does not remove the commas.

Comment: @Duncan `\K` wasn't added until Perl 5.10, so that won't work. You can use a capturing group as an alternative.

Comment: @Duncan: try `$string =~ s/((?:\G(?!\A)|[^"]*")[^",]*)(?:,|("[^"]*(?:"|\z)))/$1$2/g;`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for your help, everybody!

Comment: Hallelujah! `<°^^^^ççççç>`

Comment: Wow, this saved me a lot of time!  thank you.

Comment: @JaredStill: other way using an evaluated replacement pattern (with the e flag): `s/".*?"/$_=$&;y|,||d;$_/ge` where `$&` is the full match and `y///d` (or `tr///d`) deletes selected characters.

Comment: @JaredStill: or shorter with a second substitution: `s/".*?"/$&=~s|,||gr/ge` (with the r flag the substitution result is returned and the read-only `$&` stays untouched).

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the nice module [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) to isolate the specific field and perform a simple transliteration to get rid of the commas:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = '06/14/2015,19:13:51,"Mrs, Nkoli,,,ka N,ebedo,,m" <ubabankoffice93@gmail.com>,1,2';
my @row = quotewords(',', 1, $str);
$row[2] =~ tr/,//d;
print join ",", @row;
```

**Output:**

```
06/14/2015,19:13:51,"Mrs Nkolika Nebedom" <ubabankoffice93@gmail.com>,1,2
```

I assume that no commas can appear legitimately in your email field. Otherwise some other replacement method is required.